# ClientInitialization error when connecting prisma with mongodb (atlas)

Tags: typescript, mongodb, prisma

I am trying to use Prisma via mongo atlas. (both prisma and @prisma/client are v4.2.1)

I am trying to connect with the following code in my index.ts file

```js
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

const main = async () => {
    await prisma.$connect()
}

main().then(async () => await prisma.$disconnect()).catch(async e => {
    console.error(e)
    await prisma.$disconnect()
})
```

However, when i run the code with `ts-node index.ts`, i get the following error

```
PrismaClientInitializationError: Error in connector: Error creating a database connection. (An error occurred during DNS resolution: proto error: io error: A socket operation was attempted to 
an unreachable network. (os error 10051))
    at startFn (E:\learning-prisma\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:25528:17) {     
  clientVersion: '4.2.1',
  errorCode: undefined
}
```

I am not quite sure whats causing this error. My mongo uri is also fine. The db is also running remotely.

Comment: You don't need to invoke $connect method explicitly, can you try invoking any CRUD query in the main function? Also is your MongoDB Atlas database reachable? In certain cases unused databases are hibernated in atlas.

Comment: @NurulSundarani same error. DB seems to be connected via mongoose, but not prisma

Comment: Does your MongoDB Instance have Replica set configured? To use Prisma with MongoDB it is required to have Replica set configured

Comment: run into the same issue, you found a solution yet?